# How the scheduler Job works in Cloud Scheduler

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I have created a job in Cloud scheduler like below:

```
Name       : Start_BOT1
Frequency  : 0 */15 * * * (Asia/Calcutta)
Target     : A topic in Pub/Sub
```

As per the Frequency the job has to start every 15 mins once. But the job is not working as expected. It runs only when we click on "Run NOW" button. 
Can someone help explain how the scheduler works in GCP and how the timezones works here.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules) you can find detailed information on Configuring Cron Job Schedules with the unix-cron format.

The 1st asterisk represents the minute

The 2th asterisk represents the hour

The 3th asterisk represents the day of month

The 4th asterisk represents the month

The 5th asterisk represents the day of the week

For step values, you correctly used the slash, executing every N steps.

For your case - running the job every 15 minutes, the configuration would be: “*/15 * * * *”

You can select the time zone for evaluating the schedules either by using the dropdown on the GCP Console Create a job screen or the gcloud --time-zone flag when you create the job. The default time-zone is Etc/UTC.